# Angular on Rails. RailsResource not connecting to Rails API

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ruby-on-rails-4, coffeescript

I'm following this tutorial [Angular on Rails](http://www.angularonrails.com/how-to-wire-up-ruby-on-rails-and-angularjs-as-a-single-page-application-gulp-version/) to connect Ruby on Rails to AngularJS frontend.

**I need to convert the RailsResource service from Coffee script to javascript** because I'm using JavaScript in my project.

```
angular.module 'fakeLunchHub', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'rails']
  .config ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) ->
    $stateProvider
      .state "home",
        url: "/",
        templateUrl: "app/main/main.html",
        controller: "MainCtrl"
      .state "groups",
        url: "/groups",
        templateUrl: "app/views/groups.html",
        controller: "GroupsCtrl"

    $urlRouterProvider.otherwise '/'

  .factory "Group", (RailsResource) ->
    class Group extends RailsResource
      @configure url: "/api/groups", name: "group"
```

I have used http://js2.coffee, but the converted JavaScript did not work.

Thank you.

When I used js2.coffee, this was the code generated for my Andelan guestList app
`guestList/client/src/app/index.js`

```
'use strict';

var __extends = function(child, parent) { for (var key in parent) { if (__hasProp.call(parent, key)) child[key] = parent[key]; } function ctor() { this.constructor = child; } ctor.prototype = parent.prototype; child.prototype = new ctor(); child.__super__ = parent.prototype; return child; },
  __hasProp = {}.hasOwnProperty;

angular.module('guestList', ['ngAnimate', 'ngCookies', 'ngTouch', 'ngSanitize', 'ngResource', 'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'rails']).config(function($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider) {
  $stateProvider.state("home", {
    url: "/",
    templateUrl: "app/main/main.html",
    controller: "MainCtrl"
  }).state("andelans", {
    url: "/andelans",
    templateUrl: "app/views/andelans.html",
    controller: "AndelansCtrl"
  });
  return $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/');
}).factory("Andelan", function(RailsResource) {
  var Andelan;
  return Andelan = (function(_super) {
    __extends(Andelan, _super);

    function Andelan() {
      return Andelan.__super__.constructor.apply(this, arguments);
    }

    Andelan.configure({
      url: "/api/andelans",
      name: "andelan"
    });

    return Andelan;

  })(RailsResource);
});

// ---
// generated by coffee-script 1.9.0
```

This is the error logged to the terminal

```
[13:47:06] Starting 'scripts'...

/Users/fiyinadebayo/rails/ceemion/guestList/client/src/app/index.js
  line 3   col 102  Expected '{' and instead saw 'child'.
  line 3   col 233  A constructor name should start with an uppercase letter.
  line 4   col 13   '__hasProp' was used before it was defined.
  line 7   col 30   Strings must use singlequote.
  line 8   col 13   Strings must use singlequote.
  line 9   col 38   Strings must use singlequote.
  line 10  col 27   Strings must use singlequote.
  line 11  col 22   Strings must use singlequote.
  line 12  col 21   Strings must use singlequote.
  line 13  col 43   Strings must use singlequote.
  line 14  col 31   Strings must use singlequote.
  line 17  col 21   Strings must use singlequote.
  line 22  col 21   'Andelan' is already defined.
  line 27  col 27   Strings must use singlequote.
  line 28  col 22   Strings must use singlequote.
  line 19  col 19   Did you mean to return a conditional instead of an assignment?

  ⚠  16 warnings


/Users/fiyinadebayo/rails/ceemion/guestList/client/src/app/controllers/andelans.controller.js
  line 8  col 14  'console' is not defined.

  ⚠  1 warning

[BS] 5 files changed (index.js, main.controller.js, main.controller.spec.js, andelans.controller.js, navbar.controller.js)
[13:47:06] all files 4.55 kB
[13:47:06] Finished 'scripts' after 190 ms
[HPM] Proxy error: ECONNREFUSED localhost:3000/api/andelans
```

Comment: Can you show your errors, pls?

Comment: Yes, can you please describe/show exactly *how* it didn't work?

Comment: I added the code generated by js2.coffee and the error logged to the terminal below the question above.